# Android - Mapbox Orientation Change Loses Reference to MapboxMap

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, mapbox, orientation-changes

Pretty self-explanatory - I have a MapboxMap in a viewpager fragment, and if the screen is rotated I lose the reference to the map (ie. map = null for any further method calls). I've implemented all the fragment state changes to the end, including OnDestroyView, so not sure whats up. Below is an excerpt from my [MapFragment.java](https://github.com/jakem742/DailyReadings/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/liftyourheads/dailyreadings/fragments/MapFragment.java).

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Attaching Map");
    super.onAttach(context);
    mContext = context;
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    Log.i(TAG,"Detaching Map");
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mMapView.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    Log.i(TAG,"Stopping Map");
    super.onStop();
    mMapView.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

/*
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG,"Destroying Map");
    super.onDestroy();
    //mMapView.onDestroy();
}
*/

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: why you have commented mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState); . Uncomment it and check it. In addition place mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); this line in onCreateView().

Comment: Plus you have to make sure that in manifest file in the activity tag (fragment containing activity) you have to specify  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" so that activity will not get detroyed and local variables will not get destroyed (or) if you want handle for orientation change with different resource you need to store mapview instance in onSaveInstanceState() in bundle and retrive in onRetriveInstanceState() and assign to it in onCreateView() method.

Comment: Yeah, fixing the rotation config helped fix that. I'm having issues still with the instance being destroyed when the activity is destroyed and I need to be able to restore it (I'm assuming using onRetrieve). I'm not sure what format to store the mapview instance in? Any suggestions would be appreciated!